# Datatables and special chars (ñ.`´,ç)

Tags: mysql, datatable, special-characters

I'm using datatables;

My wordpress form stores data from a form to the database, here, every rhing works fine, special characters are stored correctly, but when I make the query with datatables, all words containing any special words appear as "null".

Any sugestion? Where or how or what should I modificate?

Thanks in advance

PD: Here you have and example:

In database I have a Column called "Surnames" if a user's surname is for example "García", inside database I see it correctly but using datatables I see: Surname":null,

Comment: What is the collation & character set of the table & the column ?

Comment: database: utf8_general_ci, column I've tested with utf8_general_ci and  utf8_spanish_ci with same results

Comment: I'm searching and I've seen, for example, that letter Ç tiped via datatables Editor is stored in Database as \u00E7 which is C/C++/Java source code.

Comment: Then it is the inserting of the data that is wrong. \u00E7 is not sourcecode, just an app that has saved some extended chars in textual unicode. See it a lot when people exporting CSV files from windows.

Answer (score 0):

The last but not the lost option to have in mind is to create a mysqli connection using utf-8 charset:

```
mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8');
```